# Calculate download speed using AJAX

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to display the download speed in real time as a file is downloaded, however the following code is not working. `Speed` returns 0.0 for the entire download.

```js
https.get(options, function (update) {
  fileSize = (parseInt(update.headers['content-length']) / 1048576).toFixed(1);
  startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  endTime = startTime;
  update.on('data', function (chunk) {
    file.write(chunk);
    len += chunk.length;
    fileDownloaded = (len / 1048576).toFixed(1);
    endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    time = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
    speed = ((fileSize / time) / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2);
    progressPercentage.html(fileDownloaded + ' MB / ' + fileSize + ' MB ' + speed + ' MB/s');
   });
});
```

Comment: If you output some more of the variables, perhaps you can identify the culprit. Where do the issues start?

Comment: @User394839859 - This is difficult to debug remotely without knowing some basics like what `update.headers['content-length']` evaluates to.  But, @CarlosCarucce is making a good point in his answer.  You need to take a least some steps to make this proper JS (by declaring variables with 'var' and the like) and then check the scope of your variables in the closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is maybe a better solution, but here we go:

```
var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
var downloadedLength = 0;

update.on('data', function (chunk) {
    // ...

    downloadedLength += chunk.length;

    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    var speed = downloadedLength / (now - startTime); //bytes/second
    //speed / 1024 should return in kilobytes

    //...
});
```

Edit:

Consider using `Date.now()` instead of `(new Date()).getTime();` for better performance

Answer (score 0):

Thought the answer provided by Carlos is great using Performance.now() instead of (new Date()).getTime() would be a better choice.

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Comment: I think `Date.now()` would be better doesnt it?